# UrlOpen Redirected to default page

Tags: python, urlopen

The default data link is http://tools.morningstar.co.uk/uk/fundscreener/results.aspx?LanguageId=en-GB&Universe=FOGBR%24%24ALL&CurrencyId=GBP&URLKey=t92wz0sj7c&Site=uk

But, I do not want data on this default page. I want the data under Portfolio tab. So, I used Firefox to determine the url of the portfolio and attempted  following python code:

```
testpage = urlopen('http://tools.morningstar.co.uk/uk/fundscreener/results.aspx?LanguageId=en-GB&Universe=FOGBR%24%24ALL&CurrencyId=GBP&URLKey=t92wz0sj7c&Site=uk&tabAction=Portfolio')
```

However, page is always redirected to the default link. How do I get to the portfolio page?

Comment: I see two portfolio tabs on the default link. Top tab and then the data tab below it. Which is it you are talking about?

Comment: Default Tab is the one named - Snapshot, I want to scrape data from Portfolio and Short Term tabs

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention to the request that is being made along with all the headers and the data.

For getting the "portfolio" data, if you inspect, you will see that `POST` request is being along with log of data is sent and `payload data` (form data) is to used to send the portfolio data back in response.

What you need to do is mimic the request to fetch the response data and then handle that according to your need. You can do something like this :

```
import requests
from lxml import html

headers = {
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6'
}

url = "http://tools.morningstar.co.uk/uk/fundscreener/results.aspx?LanguageId=en-GB&Universe=FOGBR%24%24ALL&CurrencyId=GBP&URLKey=t92wz0sj7c&Site=uk"

payload = {
    'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_aFundScreenerResultControl_ScriptManager1_HiddenField':';;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.7.123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-GB:5a4df314-b4a2-4da2-a207-9284f1b1e96c:de1feab2:f2c8e708:720a52bf:f9cec9bc:589eaa30:a67c2700:ab09e3fe:87104b7c:8613aea7:3202a5a2:be6fb298',
    '__EVENTTARGET':'TabAction',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'Portfolio',
    '__LASTFOCUS':'',
    '__VIEWSTATE':'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',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'7400285C',
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':'',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION':'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',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$ddlPageSize':'20',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$hdnFilterBySelection':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$hdnSelectedIndex':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$hdnSelectedFunds':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$hdnCustomImageFileIds':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$hdnSelectedSecurityCount':'0',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$hdnTabs':'Snapshot,ShortTerm,Performance,Portfolio,FeesAndDetails',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$msExportToExcel$hdnSelectedRow':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$msExportToExcel$hdnCheckedColumns':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$msExportToExcel$hdnExportLimit':'50',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$msExportToExcel$hdnExportCount':'0',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$msExportToExcel$toExport':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$msExportToExcel$hdnAllowAllFundsExport':'true',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$aFundScreenerResultControl$txtSaveSearch':'',
    'ctl00$__RequestVerificationToken':'e_BrPK0DxBjkgMrhfkdyFJjp1nPzltSn0h20aUjHJPSe3W4w3FRsFQNo_YY3Ml0D1CkNGqC5PEJBigtZuvdbiYrldSMrUoOQFUjaPifPbM41'
}

r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = payload)
print(r.content)

root = html.fromstring(r.content)
```

You can now fetch the elements you need from root using xpath such as :

```
root.xpath('//input[@class="some_class"]')
```

Refer to [scraping](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) documentation for more understanding.

I have used all the payload data from the request, you can remove some and check for what is absolutely necessary for the request.

Also, follow the website rules about scraping and scrape gracefully without putting too much pressure on the website.

Comment: Thanks Satish. The table with class name = 'gridView tabPortfolio' is missing in the output. M afraid there is no progress on the issue.

Comment: The content may be loaded dynamically by JS. Check the source and not the element part in your browser for that.